# What test do I use to see the effect of a rule variation on a game?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference, games

Let's say two people play a skill-based game and a winner is decided. Then a rule variation is introduced and the same two people play the game again. This process is then repeated with different pairs of people. More often than not, the same player (the better one) will win both games but sometimes the other player will win and I want to know whether or not the rule variation had a statistically significant impact on the outcome.

What would be the appropriate test to use?